# OperationalError at /admin/weather/comment/ no such column: weather_comment.author_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to add comments, and I have OperationalError at /admin/weather/comment/:`no such column: weather_comment.author_id`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} {self.title}'


class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_commented = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed author field in Comment on

```
author=models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,null=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error you get when you fail to run or rerun the migration after you changed item(s) in the models.py.

#try

python manage.py runmigrations
python manage.py migrate